# How to perform XML transformations with Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

What does Ballerina offer to perform transformations with XML? Options for Xpath, Xsd, Xslt? I'm studying Ballerina and found no good options for performing XML queries and transformations.

Comment: This support is not still available in Ballerina https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/4224

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ballerina still does not have OOB support for XSLT yet. However, there is enough support from the language syntax to write your own transformer. It provides a xpath alike syntax to access elements and attributes.

eg:

```
xml bookXML = xml `<book>
            <name>Sherlock Holmes</name>
            <author>
                <fname title="Sir">Arthur</fname>
                <mname>Conan</mname>
                <lname>Doyle</lname>
            </author>
            <!--Price: $10-->
            </book>`;

// Can access inner elements using field-access syntax, and attribute using '@' sign.
string title = bookXML.author.fname@["title"]

// OR
string title = bookXML["author"]["fname"]@["title"]
```

There's is another bunch of native functions as well, to perform other XML manipulations like `selectDescendants()`, `slice()`, etc. Those can be found at [1].

Similarly, you can write your own XSD parser, and a validator using the above language features.

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/xml-functions.html

Comment: Thank you so much!